# jQuery - execute a block of code in one line

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a block of code:

```
                $('#link_dwebsitedesign a').removeClass('selected');
            $('#link_dhuisstijl a').removeClass('selected');
            $('#link_dhosting a').removeClass('selected');
            $('#link_dwordpress a').removeClass('selected');
            $('#link_dseo a').removeClass('selected');
            $('#link_dcms a').removeClass('selected');
            $('#link_dslicen a').removeClass('selected');
            $('#link_dwebshop a').removeClass('selected');
```

And it needs to be executed several times in my script.

Isn't there a selector or anything so i can execute this block of code in one line?

Example: `$('blockofcode').execute();`

Comment: Depending on your HTML and everything, `$('a').removeClass('selected')` might be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the code in a function:

```
     function mycode(){
        $('#link_dwebsitedesign a').removeClass('selected');
        $('#link_dhuisstijl a').removeClass('selected');
        $('#link_dhosting a').removeClass('selected');
        $('#link_dwordpress a').removeClass('selected');
        $('#link_dseo a').removeClass('selected');
        $('#link_dcms a').removeClass('selected');
        $('#link_dslicen a').removeClass('selected');
        $('#link_dwebshop a').removeClass('selected');
     }
```

And call your function wherever you want:

```
mycode();
```

See [Javascript Functions](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptfunction.php) tutorial for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest it could be shortened:

```
$('#link_dwebsitedesign a, #link_dhuisstijl a, #link_dhosting a, #link_dwordpress a, #link_dseo a,#link_dcms a, #link_dslicen a, #link_dwebshop a').toggleClass('selected');
```

Which does the same thing. You could put that in a function like so:

```
function jQuery_ToggleSelected()  
{  
    $('#link_dwebsitedesign a, #link_dhuisstijl a, #link_dhosting a, #link_dwordpress a, #link_dseo a,#link_dcms a, #link_dslicen a, #link_dwebshop a').toggleClass('selected');    
}
```

And just called `jQuery_ToggleSelected()` to add/remove the desired style to those elements.

Answer (score 1):

Create a small plugin that does this for you, since you seem to be doing it all the time:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.removeSelected = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
         $('a', this).removeClass('selected');
     });   
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Then pass `jQuery` an array of selectors to remove the class...

```
var links_array = ['#link_dwebsitedesign', '#link_dhuisstijl', '#link_dhuisstijl', '#link_dwordpress', '#link_dseo', '#link_dcms', '#link_dslicen', '#link_dwebshop'];

function removeLinks(links) {
    $(links.join(', ')).removeSelected();
}
removeLinks(links_array);
```

And voila!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a class that is the same for all and call

```
$('.link a').removeClass('selected');
```

Or if you know what element you are calling you can remove all the ones with ids beginning with link (using div):

```
   $('div[id^=link_] a').removeClass('selected');
```

Or call everything from a function

```
function removeLinkSelects(){
    $('#link_dwebsitedesign a').removeClass('selected');
    $('#link_dhuisstijl a').removeClass('selected');
    $('#link_dhosting a').removeClass('selected');
    $('#link_dwordpress a').removeClass('selected');
    $('#link_dseo a').removeClass('selected');
    $('#link_dcms a').removeClass('selected');
    $('#link_dslicen a').removeClass('selected');
    $('#link_dwebshop a').removeClass('selected');
}
removeLinkSelects();
```

I'd probably be most likely to use those in that order, if I couldn't/didn't want to add a class use the attr selector and if that was wildly different use a function.
Although in terms of the way the code looks like it could be structured I'd be more inclined to use  but obviously I don't know why you've marked them up like that and most likely it's perfectly logical

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a function and then call the function instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would give all those `#link_dwebsitedesign, #link_dhuisstijl`, etc. elements a common class, for example `class="link"`, then just use [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) like this:

```
$(".link a").removeClass("selected");
```

You can do this anywhere you find yourself repeating code...if you want to handle elements in a batch, use a common class to identify them, then operate on *that* class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#link_dwebsitedesign a , #link_dhuisstijl a, #link_dhosting a, #link_dwordpress a, #link_dseo a, #link_dcms a, #link_dslicen a, #link_dwebshop a').removeClass('selected');
```

Or put it in a Function